# Transplant shock avocado tree

Tags: transplanting, avocado, leaf

[image]I have inherited from a friend an avocado plant (around 5 years old). After 2 months of acclimatation in the new home, I decided to transplant it 2 weeks ago. As the soil it was in, had never been changed (it was really dry and compact) and the pot was looking too small. Unfortunately, I lost a lot of the small roots while transferring. Now the avocado is in a new soil, but didn't liked the transfer at all. I guess it lost too many small roots. All the leaves are dry and the stems are floppy (still green thought).

I moved it to a more shaded area, and tried to not overwater it (the soil is humid but not damp).

Is there anything I can do to help it, or it is too late ? :,(

Comment: Hi Naomie, can you add a picture?...and where you are located?

Comment: Spray water daily and pray at the same time. You repotted drastically and left the plant to recuperate in full sun? No SPF?

Comment: Throw a dry-cleaner bag over it to simulate a greenhouse for a week until recovery.

Comment: I added a picture for info. I am located in Tasmania (below Australia). The climate here is quite temperate, we are in early spring now. The plant is next to a big window, facing East, it is getting the morning sun, but no direct sun in the afternoon. Should I avoid direct sun even in the morning? I started spraying the leaves, stem and soil, thank you for the tip.     The point of the plastic bag is to keep the moist while getting the temperature up ?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say that tree looks very sad.  Avocados are trees so they are vigorous if well established.

Check to see if there is living tissue by making a small longitudinal cut in the bark.  If the tree is still alive there will be a small amount of green tissue under the bark.

Don't bother with bags or fertilizer or spraying with water.  Remove all dead leaves, give it a good water and be very, very patient.  If you don't see any new growth in four to six weeks then it is gone.

Answer (score 0):

OK @Naomie this is going to be tell-off, sorry! Repotting is done by - in my subjective experience - procuring a larger pot with new soil but a hole as large as the old container - and dropping all the old soil with minimal disturbance.

If the old soil was caked up do air it up AFTER the even but do note it has been mistreated to get there.